# HTML/CSS - Setting Select Menu Style

Tags: html, css, select, drop-down-menu

I'm using several  dropdown menus for a site I'm working on. In Chrome and Safari the menus render fine. But in firefox, the dropdown arrow is placed in the middle of the menu.

---

EDIT
Here's pictures.

This is what it should look like in all browsers. (It's only like this in Chrome.)
[image]

This is what it's currently doing in Firefox and IE:

[image]

**How can I fix this?**

Comment: Please post your html / css and screengrab

Comment: i think you need to bring up your code. Or your URL here.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use background position:right center; in CSS. This might help

Answer (score 0):

Styling a `select` element is a royal pain in the butt. I would suggest *not* using a `select` element, and instead use `radio buttons` + `labels` + `JavaScript` to emulate a select element. It will give you more control over the styling, and still maintain accessibility (if done correctly).

I believe there is a jQuery plugin to do this (I know you didn't tag JavaScript or jQuery).

The markup could look something like this:

```
<ul class="select-replacement">
  <li>
    <input type="radio" id="option1" name="selectElementName" value="value 1" />
    <label for="option1">Value 1</label>
  </li>
  ...
</ul>
```

And just to show that I'm not full of it here's a [jsfiddle of a pure HTML+CSS `select` style element without actually using a `select` element](http://www.jsfiddle.net/3tDnq/). It's a 3 minute hack-job, and JavaScript would make it much cleaner/work in Internet Exploder.